# It is legal to create a wallpaper featuring character names?

Tags: legal

For instance lets say that I create a wallpaper featuring the names of the heroes from the video games Dota 2 or Smite and sell it. Is this a IP violation/infringement? Or it can be done without license from the IP holders?

Comment: You really need to ask a lawyer, not a graphic designer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a legal question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dota is a registered trademark. You can use text "Dota" in a writing which tells of game Dota 2 for ex. how bad it is - like a review. But the trademark owner can sue you if he notices that you try to rise the value of some product by using the name or the logo of the game as artistic or decorative content.

The possibility to get sued by trademark owners is typical in the western hemisphere, but this all varies between different countries. If you happen to live for ex. in North Korea and know the right people you can use western trademarks as you like assuming you know how to avoid collecting difficulties which are typical there, but unknown for ex. in USA or western Europe.

To be sure how things are where you live, get a lawyer who knows the local law!

By the way I'm afraid no court of law would believe you if you happened to print game logo or name or both to a cloth and claimed "these are not intended to be used as cloths, they are printed game reviews".